# Is there a way to make datatables in yii2 load data not on page load, but on keyup/enter?

Tags: javascript, php, gridview, datatables, yii2

I am using datatables and gridview in yii2 to display data.  Is there anyway to make datatables load the data not on page load, but on keyup and/or submit button? Right now all the data displays on page load and then when you type or hit enter datatables narrows the data.

Answer (score 0):

not exactly what you are asking for, but maybe this might help.
i think you could return an empty result by default, because you use a hidden field in your condition (default 0, condition 1 = field value). in your view you could set this hidden field's value with javascript which then allows your query to return results. reload your grid. (my javascript reloads the grid every 5000ms)

```
function reloadGrid() {
    $('#access-log-grid').yiiGridView('applyFilter');
}

$(document).ready(function() {

    $('#pjax-access-log-index').on('pjax:start', function() {
        if (timer) clearTimeout(timer);
    })

    $('#pjax-access-log-index').on('pjax:end', function() {
        timer = setTimeout(reloadGrid, 5000);
    })

    timer = setTimeout(reloadGrid, 5000);
});
```

Comment: where do I set the default to be empty? Can you show me an example? Also, what file would I have to modify in order to do this?

Comment: in your search model, add a new public property public $block.
in function rules(), set '$block' default value1.
query: if ($this->block == 1) $query->where('0=1')